# Failed to resolve: com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Just started `Android development`. Adding Facebook integration, but get this error with `Gradle`. Tried rebuild and `Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle files`. None of them helps.

Added line to `Module: app`.

`compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'`

Comment: Check the compatibility have you changed the compile version or other dependencies recently

Comment: recently downloaded Android Studio

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you added

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

In your **`project`** level **`build.gradle`**. if not please add.

also add `mavenCentral()` to **`allprojects`**.

```
    allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()    
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Otherwise, I think they  did not update their Maven repo. Meanwhile please use below dependency for Facebook

```
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
```

Comment: `facebook-android-sdk` helped

Comment: You only really need mavenCentral() there